# MongoDB snapshot

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo to insert and retrieve data from MongoDB. These two operations may be performed simultaneously. The question is when I do `rows = db.<collection>.find()` in pymongo, every time `rows.count()` returns a different response (since insertion of data is also being done at the same time). Is there some way I can limit MongoDB to return only the rows that were present when I executed the `find()` statement? I tried adding `snapshot=True` to `find()` but the problem persists.

Comment: Adding snapshot=True worked for me. I got a cursor after doing find(), I then stored the count(), iterated over the cursor inserting new documents on each iteration and then when this was finished I did another count() on the same cursor and verified it was the same as the first stored count(). Incidently, snapshot also fixes update() from changing the number of documents iterated as well. See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/0bCEb7vcUvg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.<collection>.find().count()` will make an additional (`runCommand` `count`) call to mongodb anyway.

How about simply taking a length of your cursor, like this:

```
rows = db.<collection>.find()
print len(list(rows))
```

Note that you can't just use `len(rows)`.

Hope that helps.